# What is the correlation between these two time series which I post here?

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, panel-data, granger-causality

Here is the figure of the two time series $A_t$ and $B_t$ for a panel data. We can see that the silent time (value equals to zero) are the same and one of time series whatevter $A_t$ or $B_t$ somehow excites another time series, meaning that if the value of $A_t$ or $B_t$ is not equal to zero then another time series is not zero too. Basically I want to use one series to predict another, so at the very begining I was searching the method of causality testing like Granger causality. But every example I saw in the internet is a .. I think it's a normal time series without such a long silent time, thus I am not sure whether Granger causality testing would work well nor not. Is there any option to model this phenomenon?

Thanks a lot!
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Time Warping might be a good choice if you are explicitly trying to use one time series to predict another.

This method works by means of determining similarity between two sequences which vary, typically in either time or speed.

From looking at your time series, it would not appear (at least visually) that there is a lag between the two time series, but this would need to be investigated further. Calculating the cross-correlation between the two time series would also be advised.

There is quite an interesting paper in which the author uses DTW to predict US recessions using Treasury term spread data. It may prove useful in informing what you are trying to accomplish.

You can find that here:

[Predicting US Recessions: A Dynamic Time Warping Exercise in Economics](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3047649)